# How to delete selected text in neovim?

Tags: vim, vimrc, neovim

I have `xnoremap <BS> "_di` this keymap in my neovim config. But when I select a text in visual mode and press backspace to delete the text, the text deletes and gets copied to my clipboard.

I'm using my system clipboard obviously.

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

How to only delete the selection and not copy it? It's frustrating...

Comment: Is "a" in your `'guioptions'`?

Comment: @Heptite is that only for the gui version of nvim? I'm not using a gui. :)

Comment: It works as expected in Vim but the clipboard is implemented differently in Neovim so your mileage may vary. FWIW, `"_c` makes more sense than `"_di`.